# How to prevent Tails OS from accessing hard drive?

Tags: linux, tor

I had a question regarding the Tails OS. I just want it for some regular Tor browsing. Is it guaranteed that the **hard disk is not accessible** in case something goes terribly wrong? (Worst case scenario?)

Comment: Why not just physically remove the hard drive ?

Comment: I'm using a laptop, and would become a hectic job to remove Hardrive for that little time on Diving the Deep. 

Answer (score 2):

Your question title and body do not match up, so I'll answer both questions...

> How to prevent Tails OS from accessing hard drive?

Use full-disk encryption on the drive (some parts are still readable/writable), or unplug the drive. There is not really another way to prevent an operating system from accessing a drive.

> Is it guaranteed that the hard disk is not accessible in case something goes terribly wrong?

No, why would this be guaranteed? Seeing how the [Tails documentation](https://tails.boum.org/doc/encryption_and_privacy/your_data_wont_be_saved_unless_explicitly_asked/index.en.html#access_hdd) has instructions on how to access your hard drive, it is completely possible to do this.

Comment: Even if you use full-disk encryption, a virus downloaded while browsing in Tails could still infect your unencrypted boot sector / boot partition, unless you used something like Secure Boot to verify the boot loader.